# how to read file ignores the first whitespace?

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a plain text file which looks like this:

```
jimmy wang man staff  
jackson man staff
```

Now, suppose the `jimmy wang` should be read as one value; this would make the whole line be parsed as three values: `jimmy wang`, `man` and `staff`. The next line should also, obviously, be parsed as three values.

I have tried to use delimiter but that would skip the first line of first whitespace into 4 variables.

Comment: Can you show your code thus far?

Comment: How do you want to split a line? You could read the whole line, split it at each space and concatenate all but the last two values.

Comment: How do you know that `jimmy wang` is "special" ???

Answer (score 0):

You could read the whole line, split it at each space and concatenate all but the last two values. Here is a pseudo code for this

```
while line = getline():
    words = split(line, ' ')
    var1 = ""
    first = true
    for word in words[0:-2]:
        if not first
            name += ' '
        first = false
        var1 += word
    var2 = words[-2]
    var3 = words[-1]
```

This pseudo code is python oriented. `words[-2]` is the last but one
 element.  `words[-1]` is the last element. `for word in words[0:-2]:` is a loop over all elements but the last two.

Answer (score -1):

read every line, split every line by ' ' (whitespace).
Now read from the back (right to left) and insert values with fixed length in your variables. The rest is the name